# Preserver double quotes in bash string when run with "bash -c"

Tags: bash, shell, echo

I have a bash variable which is stored as

```
var="\"abc\""
```

So, when i locally print this variable it gives me proper output(with double quotes)

```
echo "$var"
"abc"
```

What, I want to do is print it using 'bash -c' option.. but when I do the same, it prints only value without double quotes.

```
bash -c "echo \"$var\""
abc
bash -c "echo $var"
abc
```

Can anyone help me on how to preserve the double quotes in my string, when I use it in 'bash -c'. And what does -c actually mean?

Comment: run `bash --help` or `man bash` and read. Same to any other Linux commands

Comment: Basically, after the substitution you are executing the following code : `bash -c "echo \""abc"\""` and `bash -c "echo "abc""` in your 1st and 2nd example respectively

Answer (score 1):

In the statement

```
bash -c "echo $var"
```

the following happens:

(1) `var` is expanded (resulting into `"abc"` including the quotes).

(2) A bash child process is invoked, receiving as first parameter `-c` and as second paramter `echo "abc"`

(3) This child process runs the command, i.e. `echo "abc"`, and according to the rules about quote removal, this is equivalent to `echo abc`, and you don't see any quotes in the output.

You may be tempted to do a

```
bash -c 'echo "$var"'
```

instead. In this case, the following happens:

(1) A bash child process is invoked, receiving as first parameter `-c` and as second paramter `echo "$var"`. Note that `$var` is not expanded yet, because it is between single quotes.

(2) This child process runs the command, i.e. `echo "$var"`. However, since we are in a child process, the variable `var` does not exist, and the command is equivalent to `echo ""`, i.e. only a newline is printed.

You can however combine both solution by doing a

```
export var
bash -c 'echo "$var"'
```

In this case, `var` is made available to the child processes of your script, and you will see the quotes being printed.

Answer (score 1):

From `info bash`

> -c        If  the  -c  option  is  present,  then  commands  are  read from the first non-option argument command_string.
> If there are arguments after the command_string, the first argument is assigned to  $0
> and  any  remaining  arguments are assigned to the positional parameters.

So the `-c` option executes the commands within the quotes.

To preserve your double quotes while calling via `bash -c`, you would need to quote the variable seperately.

```
$ bash -c "echo '"$var"'"
"abc"
```

Answer (score 0):

When trying to preserve the quotes in a command this can also be done without variable:

```bash
bash -c "echo \\\"abc\\\""
```

Hereby the `\\` reduce to `\` and the `\"` to `"` in the subshell, which composes to

```bash
echo \"abc\"
```

yielding the output

```
"abc"
```

I needed quote escaping in a docker [RUN directive](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) like

```
RUN "sed -i \"s/\\\"string-sourrounded-by-quotes\\\"/\\\"new-string\\\"/\" file"
```

because it will be run in a shell process, defined by the SHELL directive. In my case the [SHELL directive](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell) was `SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c"]`, which resulted in:

```bash
/bin/bash -o pipefail -c "sed -i \"s/\\\"quoted-string\\\"/new-string/\" file"
```

and that is executed as

```bash
sed -i "s/\"quoted-string\"/new-string/" file
```